# brew link jpeg issues

Tags: opencv, osx-lion, symlink, homebrew

I am trying to install `opencv` on Mac OSX Lion.

`brew install opencv`

I get the following error (and a few other similar ones)

```
Error: The linking step did not complete successfully
The formula built, but is not symlinked into /usr/local
You can try again using `brew link jpeg'
```

When I do

```
brew link jpeg
Linking /usr/local/Cellar/jpeg/8d... ln: wrjpgcom: File exists
```

I do not understand what this means? What should I be doing? Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Check for the following files in the `/usr/local` folder:

```
bin/cjpeg
bin/djpeg
bin/jpegtran
bin/rdjpgcom
bin/wrjpgcom
include/jconfig.h
include/jerror.h
include/jmorecfg.h
include/jpeglib.h
lib/libjpeg.8.dylib
lib/libjpeg.a
share/man/man1/cjpeg.1
share/man/man1/djpeg.1
share/man/man1/jpegtran.1
share/man/man1/rdjpgcom.1
share/man/man1/wrjpgcom.1
```

For `brew link jpeg`to succeed:

1. Remove (and backup) any of the aforementioned files
2. launch `brew link jpeg` again.

Comment: I individually deleted each file that `brew link jpeg` kept throwing back as an error.

Answer (score 3):

Find the file wrjpgcom outside the Cellar and delete it.

The problem is Homebrew is trying to symlink that file into /usr/local but the destination for the symlink already exists as another file.

Comment: There are so many files that have to be deleted. And the deleted files keep coming back. Is there an easier way?

Comment: `brew ls --unbrewed` will list everything you installed and that Homebrew **did not** install. You can pass that to rm at your own risk.