# Imagemagick 6.8.10 on mountain lion using rails issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, homebrew

My code is here: https://github.com/pavankat/to_do_app

I used this tutorial: http://guides.railsgirls.com/thumbnails/

- After running through the tutorial for a bit I got this error when trying to edit idea 1's picture (pretty much reupload the picture) so the thumbnail would appear:

  Picture Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: MiniMagick::Invalid

I thought it was happening because I didn't restart the server, but I did that and it still happened.

I followed the instructions here: [Rails and OS X: How to install rmagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13963404/rails-and-os-x-how-to-install-rmagick) (question by TaianSu and chad bidwell), but no luck.

Then I followed this: [Why is this RMagick call generating a segmentation fault?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838307/why-is-this-rmagick-call-generating-a-segmentation-fault) (Ash Berlin's response)

```
$ brew uninstall imagemagick && brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp
Uninstalling /usr/local/Cellar/imagemagick/6.8.0-10...


Error: You must `brew link jpeg' before imagemagick can be installed
```

so I did this:

```
$ brew rm jpeg
```

and then

```
$ brew install imagemagick --disable-openmp
```

then I restarted the server

I still get the error when making an idea or editing an idea's picture: Picture Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: MiniMagick::Invalid

I did this:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /usr/local
```

but no luck

Tried this based on [carrierwave + mini_magick gems = not an image error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9905499/carrierwave-mini-magick-gems-not-an-image-error) (B. Ruschill's response):

```
$ brew uninstall imagemagick
$ brew cleanup --force -s
$ brew rm jpeg
$ brew install imagemagick
```

but then it gave me an error that it couldn't link jpeg.

so I tried brew link jpeg. That didn't work.

so I tried [brew link jpeg issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9762943/brew-link-jpeg-issues) (David Riccitelli's response)

and I tried brew link jpeg again. That didn't work.

Comment: Did you find an answer yet?

Comment: @GerardWesterhof never did unfortunately. I would stay away from Imagemagick and use another one. Try ruby tool box to find another gem to try out.